# Передача переменных из PHP к JS способом слабоумного

Tags: javascript, php, html

Пытаюсь передать переменные php в js чтобы он в свою очередь вывел их на html. Есть три файла `index.php` `updateCounter.php` и `main.js`. Файл `updateCounter.php` содержит такой код

```php
<?php

    // Infected ================================================
    $filename = 'infected';
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');

    $content = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($handle);

    $content += 1;

    $infected = $content; // Сохраняю новое значение в переменную
    file_put_contents($filename, $content);


    // Deaths ==================================================
    $filename = 'deaths';
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');  

    $content = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($handle);  

    $content += 2;

    $deaths = $content; // Сохраняю новое значение в переменную  
    file_put_contents($filename, $content);


    // Damage ===================================================
    $filename = 'damage';
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb'); 

    $content = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($handle); 

    $content += 7756;

    $damage = $content; // Сохраняю новое значение в переменную
    file_put_contents($filename, $content);

    ?>
```

Здесь я беру значения из трех файлов, прибавляю к этому значение какое то число, потом сохраняю новое значение в переменную и так же это новое значение записываю в файл при этом удаляя старое содержимое файла(перезапись). **Файл `updateCounter.php` стоит как `Cron задача` и выполняется каждый 1 час.** *(иначе бы я записал все прямо в html)*

Мне нужно передать переменные `$infected` `$deaths` `$damage` в js чтобы он вывел их в соответствующие теги. Я думал передать из php в html используя `data`, потом методом `dataset` из js обратно передать их в html, но уже в другие теги. Помогите пожалуйста с реализацией. Гуглил ничего не нашел

Comment: Для этого есть база данных, зачем изобретать велосипед, пытаясь хранить данные в файлах?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov я не умею юзать базу данных, написал же "слабоумного"

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, не всегда! если это какой-либо сервис по сбору данных с датчика(температуры за окном) на микроконтроллере - там нет и не нужна никакая БД ...

Comment: @MidNightElf, и все же, не помешает уточнить:  это для решения какой-то реальной задачи или просто поиграться? есть такая штукак как sqlite, работа с ним будет не сложнее чтения файла

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$a = json_decode(file_get_contents("filename.json"), true);
$a['infected'] = 45;
$a['damage'] = 12;
$a['deaths'] = 45;
file_put_contents("filename.json", json_encode($a));
```

Читаеться со стороны JS через обычный FetchAPI:

- fetch - https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch

```
fetch("/my.json")
    .then(response => {
        if(!response.ok) throw new Error('response.ok false')
        return response.json()
    })
    .then(data => {
        document.getElementById('deaths').innerHTML = data.deaths;
        document.getElementById('kills').innerHTML = data.kills;
        document.getElementById('infects').innerHTML = data.infects;
    })
```

Comment: 1. Читает json файл который выглядит как {"infected":45,"damage":12,"deaths":45}   2. Изменяет значения    3. Записывает массив  обратно в файл.

Comment: По сути JSON один из самых нативных форматов JavaScript, и просто интерпритируется как обьект в JS.

Comment: выходит у меня будет   .json файл с 3 тремя моими переменным. И я буду с помощью php каждый час добавлять к ним число. Изменения сохраняются в файле и с помощью js я беру эти значения из json?

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6245c80316686ad07ed0cca2bd3f6e89e52184e2

Comment: Да именно так, JS просто читает JSON.. А PHP и читает и пишет json файл, а с данными работает как с обычным массивом.

Comment: Где 3 простейших шага  1. fetch - получить  2. Преобразовать в JSON и 3. перенести данные в элементы с нужными id  как например <a id="damage"></a> будет после содержать то что ты записал в $a["damage"]